# В событии передать параметры в useState и запустить setDataTimeGame

Tags: reactjs

Нужно в событии **onClockClose** запустить setDataTimeGame.

Можно сделать дополнительную кнопку, где **onClick** запускает **setDataTimeGame**. Как это сделать в одном событии **onClockClose** DateTimePicker ?

```
const DeviceListStart = observer(() => {

const [valueDataTime, setDataTime] = useState(new Date());
const [dataTimeUser, setDataTimeUser] = useState(0)
const [dataTimeOpp, setDataTimeOpp] = useState(0)

const setDataTimeGame = async () => {
           await postDataTimeGame(dataTimeUser, dataTimeOpp, valueDataTime);
     }

   return (
           <DateTimePicker
            onChange={setDataTime}
            value={valueDataTime}

            onClockClose={() => {
                setDataTimeUser(id: 1)
                setDataTimeOpp(id: 2)

                setDataTimeGame?
            }}

            //так же не работает
            onKeyPress={event => {
                if (event.key === "Enter") {
                                        
                    return setDataTimeGame
                }
             }}


   />})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return setDataTimeGame()


onClockClose={() => {
            setDataTimeUser(id: 1)
            setDataTimeOpp(id: 2)

            return setDataTimeGame()
        }}


onKeyPress={event => {
            if (event.key === "Enter") {
                                  
                return setDataTimeGame()
            }
         }}
```